cannot find -lSDL2_gfx: No such file or directory
I've decided to learn SDL2 and I added features like gfx and ttf to my SDL2 project but I've kept getting the same issue over and over (the one in the title)
[package]
name = "game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.sdl2]
version = "0.37.0"
default-features = false
features = ["ttf","image","gfx","mixer"]

[dependencies]
rand = "0.3"

This is my Cargo.toml is there any solution to this issue?

Do you have the development library sdl2_gfx installed? On arch that would probably be extra/sdl2_gfx on other distributions it should be a similar name, possibly additionally with a -dev suffix or similar. There is a whole section on the library requirements in the docs make sure you have the necessary bits installed.

I am on arch and yes I have sdl2_gfx installed

Ok so you must include more information, because with your Cargo.toml and the extra/sdl2_gfx package installed this simply works on my end. We need something reproducible to be able to help you, a [mre]. So please [edit] your question to include the complete error message from the compiler (possibly with RUST_BACKTRACE=full) and anything else that's necessary to reproduce.

i've sent Cargo.toml already but my error message is big so I will send pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/NWbka6Dh
